# realsitic gold material

Tags: rendering, materials

could somebody help me with achieving a rly realistic gold material for my jewellery designs? I have been trying to achieve it for months but could not obtain satisfactory results. The gold material should aprox. look like in this figure. For enyone helping thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: You don't show any images of your attempts or the settings you've tried, however  there are several YT tutorials online for making procedural gold material, for instance [this](https://youtu.be/XXZtuPVTU6o). one by Ryan King which is pretty realistic.

Comment: As @JohnEason said, you do not show any effort of your own or where you are stuck. Apart from having a lot of tutorials to choose from, it is even unclear under which lighting conditions the reference images are made. Almost all materials and metallic ones definitely can vary a lot under different lighting conditions, so what might seem perfect in one environment you might not like in another. For example, here I've made a single gold material and use 4 different HDRIs: [gold in different environments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxI87.jpg)

Comment: Incidentally this is the third time you've asked this question, the previous two being in May and June and each time you've been shown an answer or given links to tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You need the pick the basic color, use a scratch metal texture that you plug into the *Roughness* input of the *Principled BSDF*, also use a *Noise Texture* to create some bumps:

[image]

As suggested by John you could use an *Ambient Occlusion* node to add a darker material in the hollows of the shape:

[image]

If you plan to sculpt some drawings, do it on a high-poly and bake the normals.

Comment: An Ambient Occlusion node might help too for the shapes that are shown in the question.

Comment: OK thanks I'm going to add that ;)